# SQlite.db file not opening

Tags: sqlite

I got .db file from my PM through mail. but i cannot open it using my terminal in Mac, when i type its name, it is creating a new db rather than opening a existed one.

Can anyone let me know whats the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: What do you exactly type in the terminal?

Comment: Forgive me if this is too obvious, but are you in the correct folder when calling *sqlite3* command? You need to be in the folder where your *noble.db* file resides.

Comment: sorry,i didn't get you, how can i be in the folder when i am in terminal page!!!!!

Comment: Check Didier answer. Also, you can use *pwd* command to see the current path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the noble.db file into a folder you have access to in read/write mode.

Note the absolute complete path of this folder (starting with a /) - let's suppose it is /foo/bar

Start your terminal application

Type cd /foo/bar

Type sqlite3 noble.db